# Add Customer reference to Odoo POS receipt

Tags: odoo-15, point-of-sale, receipt

We can configure Odoo POS to create an invoice for every order, so we will find an invoice in the menu Accounting>invoices for every POS order.
In every invoice page there is a tab named "other info" which includes the feild (customer reference).
my question is, can I simply add this "customer reference" to the POS printed receipt?

I tried to add a code to the file of the printed receipt addons/point_of_sale/static/src/xml/Screens/ReceiptScreen/OrderReceipt.xml

this is the code I added
`<t t-if="o.customer_ref"><span t-field="o.customer_ref"/></span></t>`
also I tried to add
`<t t-esc='widget.pos.get_client().customer_ref'/>`

but not succeeded
is there a simple code to add the "customer reference" to the POS printed receipt or it is not that simple??

Comment: Is this helpful? https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-customize-pos-receipts-in-odoo15

Answer (score 0):

`<t t-if="receipt.customer_ref">Customer Ref: <t t-esc="receipt.customer_ref"/>`

this is the correct code